# For loop to produce a sequence of numbers

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am struggling with a particular sequence from a worksheet I'm working on in uni.

I am supposed to write/modify **for** loops to produce the following sequences:

1. 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
2. 10, 13, 16, 19
3. 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16
4. 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12
5. 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100
6. -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4,  6, 8, 10
7. -20, -15, -10, -5, 5, 10, 15, 20

I've been flying through the first 4, but the 5th one is just not getting through to me.

This is what I've been doing so far. The 6th and 7th are fine, but the 5th is confusing the heck out of me.

```
public class Lab4_4 {
    static public void main(String args[]){

        int i;

        System.out.println("Demo Sequence");
        for(i=0;i<10;++i){
            System.out.println(i);
        }

        System.out.println("First Sequence");
        for(i=4;i<=11;++i){
            System.out.println(i);
        }

        System.out.println("Second Sequence");
        for(i=10;i<=19;++i){
            System.out.println(i);
        }

        System.out.println("Third Sequence");
        for(i=1;i<=16;i +=3){
            System.out.println(i);
        }

        System.out.println("Fourth Sequence");
        for(i=2;i<=12;i +=2){
           System.out.println(i);
        }       

    }
}
```

I need some enlightenment with this problem. Also, feel free to drop any advice on how I've gone though those loops :)

EDIT: I thought the 7th is just a +5 thing but it should skip 0 so it goes from -5 to 5. Not quite sure what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: Instead of using for loops, why don't you just use [`IntStream`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) they sound perfect for what you are doing?

Comment: They are sequential squares.

Comment: Sequence 5 is simply `index^2` where index starts at 1.

Comment: You could also solve it as a sequential addition of sequentially-incremented odd numbers.  Which may confuse the instructor.

Comment: As David said, I think we're supposed to keep it simple as we're at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
    System.out.println(i*i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Fifth Sequence");
for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
    // System.out.println(i^2); // first but wrong answer...
    System.out.println(Math.pow(i,2));
}
```

but I dare say this is a "problem-solving" question rather than a loop one ;)

Comment: `i^2` does not do what you think it does

Comment: Well, it seems my memory failed me... sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.out.println("Second Sequence");
    for (int i = 10; i <= 19; ++i) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    System.out.println("Third Sequence");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i += 3) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    System.out.println("Fifth Sequence");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
        System.out.println(i * i);
    }

    System.out.println("Sixth Sequence");
    for (int i = -10; i <= 10; i = i + 2) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    System.out.println("Seventh Sequence");
    for (int i = -20; i <= 10; i = i + 5) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```